# Facebook iFrame Performance

Tags: javascript, facebook, performance, iframe

I have build a nice Game that's running on Facebook. It works down to IE8 and also runs in major mobile Browsers. I have one problem for which I didn't find any solution or clue yet: The Performance in a Facebook-Tab is noticeable slower than outside of Facebook. On Desktop this is not a big problem, but on an iPad Mini it performs very poorly.

I used Instruments on Mac to measure the implications of Facebook: The Memory-Usage is about 50% higher and the CPU-Usage seems to be about 4 times higher than outside of Facebook. First I thought it's the iFrame, but a test leeds to the conclusion, that this is not the case. So I think, it must be Facebook itself.

I thought a solution could be to disable autoGrowth, but this doesn't help either. So my question is: Did anyone else faced this Problem? Has anyone an idea how to resolve it? I've searched many blogs, the Facebook Dev-Site and also stackoverflow - without any success.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Could you give some adress where to find it? Could be a lot of things if no code can be seen.

Comment: Sure, but it's in german language: [Non-Facebook](https://www.lensspirit.de/super-strooper/#/), [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/Lensspirit/app_270037989815638?ref=br_tf)

Comment: It uses a Starling-like Juggler based on `requestAnimationFrame` (or `setTimeout`). The most costly work is a Spritesheet-Animation. On Desktop as well as on iPad Mini (non-facebook) it runs smoothly and nice. In the Facebook-Tab on an iPad Mini it is very slow, so I had to implement Frame-Skipping...